# Request Write Permission on Web Setup

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, file-permissions

In the `File System Editor` under the Web Setup project I have

[image]

witch says that my `Sripts` folder should have Write Access ... but once installed I do not have the user `IIS_USR`/`IIS_WPG` (Anonymous User or/and Worker Process) in that folder, and for such, no write access to that folder when used from a hosted level.

This is what I get:

[image]

but **I should** have this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AllowWriteAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w13ws7w%28VS.71%29.aspx) is used by IIS Web Properties dialog. It's not used to set permissions on the actual folder on disk. Your folder will use default permissions when installed.

To set custom permissions you can try using [XCACLS.EXE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754) as a [custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).